# Invert an apply with rbind

Tags: arrays, r

Lets say that I have an array, `foo`, in R that has dimensions == `c(150, 40, 30)`.
Now, if I:

```
bar <- apply(foo, 3, rbind)
```

`dim(bar)` is now `c(6000, 30)`.

What is the most elegant and generic way to invert this procedure and go from `bar` to `foo` so that they are identical?

The trouble isn't getting the dimensions right, but getting the data back in the same order, within it's respected, original, dimension.

Thank you for taking the time, I look forward to your responses.

P.S. For those thinking that this is part of a larger problem, it is, and no, I cannot use `plyr`, quite yet.

Comment: Have you looked at `aaply`? It usually does a better job of giving the dimensions you expect

Comment: The call to `rbind` doesn't make sense - since you only give it one argument, it won't do anything useful. `identity` would do the same thing... I expanded on this observation in my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can just call `array` again and specify the original dimensions:

```
m <- array(1:210,dim = c(5,6,7))
m1 <- apply(m, 3, rbind)
m2 <- array(as.vector(m1),dim = c(5,6,7))
all.equal(m,m2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought I tried this, but must be one of those nights because this works just fine. Thank you kindly!

Comment: Depending on the order of the data, you may need to create the array with the dimensions in the wrong order and then use 'aperm'.

Answer (score 4):

I'm wondering about your initial transformation. You call `rbind` from `apply`, but that won't do anything - you could just as well have called `identity`!

```
foo <- array(seq(150*40*30), c(150, 40, 30))
bar <- apply(foo, 3, rbind)
bar2 <- apply(foo, 3, identity)
identical(bar, bar2) # TRUE
```

So, what is it you really wanted to accomplish? I was under the assumption that you had a couple (30) matrix slices and wanted to stack them and then unstack them again. If so, the code would be more involved than @joran suggested. You need some calls to `aperm` (as @Patrick Burns suggested):

```
# Make a sample 3 dimensional array (two 4x3 matrix slices):
m <- array(1:24, 4:2)

# Stack the matrix slices on top of each other
m2 <- matrix(aperm(m, c(1,3,2)), ncol=ncol(m))

# Reverse the process
m3 <- aperm(array(m2, c(nrow(m),dim(m)[[3]],ncol(m))), c(1,3,2))

identical(m3,m) # TRUE
```

In any case, `aperm` is really powerful (and somewhat confusing). Well worth learning...

Comment: Good point, a breaking down of the first two dimensions is essentially what I need.

`aperm` seems a bit odd at first, but I'll look into it. It may be the best method. Thank you kindly for the suggestion.